# getPageSource() in Selenium WebDriver(a.k.a Selenium2) using Java

Tags: java, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, assertion

How can I view the source of a page between the "title" and "meta" tags using Selenium WebDriver with Java?

Answer (score 15):

You can try `driver.getPageSource()` after you have loaded the page.

[link to java doc](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebDriver.html#getPageSource--)

Comment: The javadoc link is broken.

Answer (score 7):

You can compare the Title of a page as below code:

```
String actualTitle = driver.getTitle();
String expectedTitle = "My Title";
assertEquals(actualTitle, expectedTitle);
```

If you want to get page source you can get by using the following java code:

```
String pageSource = driver.getPageSource();
```

If you want to verify a particular text is present or not on the page, do as below:

```
boolean isTheTextPresent = driver.getPageSource().contains("your text");
assertTrue(isTheTextPresent);
```