# How to verify page title using getpagesource() as it is not returning the correct page source

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am writing simply get page source function to get page source and when I am printing it, it is not printing the same source which I am getting using View Page Source.

```
String Source = driver.getPageSource();
System.out.println(Source);
```

Comment: You actually pass a String literal in the print statement. Try my code it is working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get page title with Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506489/get-page-title-with-selenium-webdriver-using-java)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this

```
driver.get("http://www.google.co.in");
String Source = driver.getPageSource();
System.out.println(Source);
```

You actually pass a `String` literal in the print statement. Just remove the double quotes in print statement

Comment: Double quotes were written there mistakenly.It is still not returning the actual page source.

Comment: Any error u got please share, Also share URL for the same

Comment: @Preet is ur problem Solved?

Comment: No, still it is not returning the actual page source.

Comment: Give me the URL and SHow me the LOG

Comment: It is working for me, Please share URL, Code or Error

Comment: I am trying to get page source of facebook.com.