# Get the inspect element variables from a website - Java

Tags: java, element, inspect

I have successfully saved the source code of a webpage but some webpages dynamically serve the info. That makes it so I cannot get the info that’s on the page.. If I right click and "inspect element" it’s there.. Is there any way to copy what is loaded from that webpage and save it to a text file?

Comment: Maybe you want JSoup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're looking for the web page source use this

Create a driver instance

```
WebDriver driver=new WebDriver();
```

call the below function when you think the dynamically served content is appeared on the web page

```
driver.getPageSource();
```

this should work.

Answer (score 0):

use selenium webdriver to get page source and even you can get the values of a particular element say inputbox, checkbox,dropdown etc from the webpage. Also you can enter the values and submit the form

```
 reate a new instance of the html unit driver
    // Notice that the remainder of the code relies on the interface, 
    // not the implementation.
    WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

    // And now use this to visit Google
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");

  System.out.println( driver.getPageSource());

    driver.quit();
}
```

}

refer [getPageSource() in Selenium WebDriver(a.k.a Selenium2) using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498779/getpagesource-in-selenium2-webdriver-using-java)

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GettingStarted