# Page source in selenium

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

How can I get page source of current page?

I make driver.get(link) and I am on main page. Then I use selenium to get other page (by tag and xpath) and when I get good page I'd like to obtain its page source.

I tried driver.page_source() but I obtain page source of main page not this current.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ccc)
driver.get('https://aaa.com')
check1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/button')
check1.click()
time.sleep(1)
check2=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/a')
check2.click()
```

And after check2.click() I am on page with new link (this link only works by click not directly). How can I get page source for this new link?

I need it to change selenium for Beautiful Soup

Comment: use this to resolve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498779/getpagesource-in-selenium-webdrivera-k-a-selenium2-using-java getPageSource() is method

Comment: @JustinLambert getPageSource() can't help becasue I use WebDriver

Comment: yes you can via Webdriver check attachment

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have used Webdriver and displaying sources of page

Comment: Thanks a lot. I edited my question. I had a code in BS but due to changes in website I have to edit it. And I only can get page link which I'm interested in by selenium. And after it I want to back to BS but I need page source of page with proper link (page where I am after check2.click). I can't do this directly using this page link because it is invalid (server error).

Comment: driver = webdriver.Chrome(ccc)
driver.get('https://aaa.com')
check1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/button')
check1.click()
time.sleep(1)
check2=driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/a')
check2.click():
driver.getPageSource():   (Please don't use absolute Xpath ,use relative Xpath in selenium)